# How to put the creation date of a page inside a paragraph on Wagtail?

Tags: python, html, wagtail

When you create a page inside the admin panel on Wagtail, it says to you how many time it has passed since then.

[image]

I want to put the time stamp of the creation of the page inside a paragraph on the HTML, like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<div class="contenedor tarjetas mt-4 mb-4">
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="fila_tarjetas clearfix">
            <div class="col_tarjeta_img">
                {% image post.blog_image fill-450x450 as blog_img %}
                <a href="{{ post.url }}">
                    <img class="tarjeta_imagen" src="{{ blog_img.url }}" alt="{{ blog_img.alt }}">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col_tarjeta_texto">
                <a class="tarjeta_titulo" href="{{ post.url }}">
                    <h3>{{ post.custom_title }}</h3>
                        <div class="tarjeta_contenido"> {{ post.content }} </div>
                    <a href="{{ post.url }}" class="leer_mas">Leer más &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; > ></a>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date you want is probably available as `post.last_published_at`. If you want to display it as an absolute date, you can use the Django template tags for formatting dates, for example `{{ post.last_published_at|date:"F d, Y" }}` Or if you want a relative date, [use the `timesince` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince)